# Start thread from function template with a function template

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates

This is my first time using templates, so I'm a little bit stuck.
What I need to do is:

1. call a function with a functor argument.
2. Start a thread inside that function with another function that also have a functor parameter.

This is what I have so far:

```
class Cls
{
public:
    template <typename Functor>
    void start(const unsigned int n, Functor f)
    {
        // This won't work
        auto b = std::bind(&Cls::run<Functor>, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
        mythread = std::thread(b, n, f);
        // This won't work too
        mythread = std::thread(&Cls::run<Functor>, this, n, f);
    }
private:
    template <typename Functor>
    void run(const unsigned int n, Functor f)
    {
        f();  // Use f() to find the meaning in life here
    }
    std::thread mythread;
}

int main()
{
    RandomClass rc;
    Cls c;
    c.start(100, std::bind(&RandomClass::randomFunc, std::ref(rc), /*randomFunc parameters here*/));

    return 0;
}
```

My knowledge about templates is little, so I really have no idea why the compiler can't find out the right number of arguments.

Comment: Your bind is missing an argument corresponding to the `unsigned int` (looks like you want a `_1` there.) Also, `f` is passed by value to `start`, so you shouldn't pass it to the thread by reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @T.C. Indeed, f should not be a reference. I tried with this call `mythread = std::thread(&Cls::run<Functor>, this, n, f);` and it is giving me this error now `'std::thread::thread' : none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types`

Comment: `run` expects 3 arguments (including the implicit `this`). Your `std::bind` is missing one.

Comment: I think I understand what you meant now. So I changed it to `auto b = std::bind(&Cls::run<Functor>, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);` but the compiler now gives `error C2860: 'void' cannot be an argument type, except for '(void)'`

Comment: It compiles in GCC and Clang, so I'm suspecting some sort of MSVC bug. Consider just using a lambda - `mythread = std::thread([this, f, n](){ run(n, f); });`.

Comment: Thank you @T.C.! It works fine with a lambda function. For the record, I'm using VC12.0.

Comment: How many times do we have to go over this? It's called a "function template", not "template function", because it's a template, *not* a function.